# Devise not routing to new controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-routing

I'm working on figuring out a Devise problem and I just can't figure it out.

I've defined a new update method within my Registrations controller that starts as:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def update
    debugger
    @user = session[:registered_as] 
    logger.info "user: #{@user}"
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
... (lots of other stuff here ) ...

def create
    build_resource
    logger.debug "I'm creating a new user "

    if resource.save
    ....
```

I call that within two forms.  One posts the create form (which works) and then I call the update form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(session[:registered_as], :as => resource_name, :url => update_user_registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
```

What I can't understand is that no matter what I do, the request to the create function goes to my overridden function while the update_user_registration method doesn't route to my new controller, but to the original Devise controller.  (i.e. when I start the server with `rails -s --debug`, the debugger is never called when RegistrationsController#update is executed).

The log output is as follows.  Note that the logger statement from the new #create method is there, but the debugger isn't:

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"adfas@ljljla.com"}}
I'm creating a new user 
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
.... 
Reason Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reasons".* FROM "reasons" 
Rendered devise/registrations/_thankyou.html.erb (22.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 30.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)

Started PUT "/user/registration.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-20 18:11:34 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0kzemeZYdnDQdV+jQJCE+tvwprPBXKZi/R9wbjsHYds=", "user"=>{"reason_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Record Your Reason"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Routes file is:

```
authenticated :user do
   root :to => 'home#index'
 end
devise_scope :user do
 root :to => "devise/registrations#new"
 match '/user/registration' => 'devise/registrations#update', :via => :put, :as => :update_user_registration
 match '/user/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :put, :as => :update_user_confirmation
end
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :confirmations => "confirmations" }
match 'users/bulk_invite/:quantity' => 'users#bulk_invite', :via => :get, :as => :bulk_invite
resources :users do
   get 'invite', :on => :member
 end
end
```

Update:  I realized that I hadn't explained the real weirdness. Explained that something passes to the original controller and something else doesn't.

Anybody have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you post your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: You've posted two different entries for the same route in different parts of your question: `match '/user/registration' => 'registrations#update'` and match `'/user/registration' => 'devise/registrations#update'`. The first will map to `RegistrationsController` and the second would map to `Devise::RegistrationsController`.

Comment: Yeah, that one was an artifact of posting the routes.rb at a different time than the original question - they were never different like that.  And I've tried taking out the devise/ in there - didn't fix anything. I've edited the question to make a little more sense, though and explain the weirdness a little more.